# pandas, slicing and creation of views

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand when pandas creates views and when copies during slicing.

To understand the behaviour I used the following:

```
# check view function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), index=list('abcdeqwrty'))
# take a slice
q = df[df[1]>0.5]
# check if it is a view (and it is)
print('q is a view {}'.format(q._is_view))
# change the view by keeping four columns, still a view
q = q.filter([0,1,2,3], axis='columns')
print('q is a view {}'.format(q._is_view))
# change the view by adding a column, not a view anymore
q['one more column'] = 'mplah'
print('q is a view {}'.format(q._is_view))
```

that prints

q is a view True
q is a view True
 
q is a view False

What is the general trend?

Many thanks for any advice and useful links.

Regards,

Panos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slice of a data frame will typically be a view, see the following links

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Hope these help.